# How can I report on how many new contacts have been entered into Civi within a specific period?

Tags: civireport

I tried:
menu Search -> Find Contacts / is - any contact type / - -> replace by the contact type you want to count (member is our subtype, but we do not have the membership module enabled, it's just the name the developers have given to the sub-contact)
click Search button

This gives me the total number of 'members', but I need to be able to report regularly on how many new individuals have joined...

Individuals are entered either by staff from within Civi, or via an online form on our website.

Thx

B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Advanced Search, then there is a section called Change Log, with an option of 'created' and you can set your date parameters including Date Range

[image]

You can also do it via Search Builder

[image]

If you cannot find Change Log there then you may need to enable Logging civicrm/admin/setting/misc?reset=1, or check your Search Display Preferences civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display?reset=1

Comment: Thanks; it works to some extent. The 'created' field only allows to choose from drop-down choices (last 7 days; from end of month prior to last month... etc.) but does not allow to choose date range (this is available for the date modified field, but 'modified' returns contacts including some who are not new contacts obviously). Would there be a way of adding a 'date range' to the field?

Comment: Yes it does allow you to specify the date range https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/search/advanced?reset=1

Comment: Thanks again. I have indeed found the 'select date range' for the 'created' field in Change Log. Not sure why I could not see it before... Thank you!

Comment: @Bern maybe you could 'accept' one of the answer so StackExchange knows it has been helpful

Answer (score 1):

There's also a Date Added search under Search - Custom Searches.

Comment: Thx; unfortunately, the Date Added does not allow me to fine tune (i.e how many new members of ethnic background with disabilities for example);  I think I need to look to Search Builder... but it's a little beyond my competences at present.... Thx for help though

Comment: Not directly but you can then create a group from the results, then include that group in advanced search.

Comment: Oh I see... I am a complete newbie, so thanks for suggestion. I will try to work that out...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a reasonably recent version of CiviCRM you can use Search Kit. This is an extension which you can install from Administer>System Settings>Extension. You can find documentation and instruction on how to use it here: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/the-user-interface/search-kit/